# Julia HTTP.get() API key Authorization

Tags: api, julia

A website I'm accessing requires an API key ID and secret key as the username and password for (I'm assuming) basic authorization.

I'm using the HTTP.get function from the HTTP module but I can't find how to include my key ID and secret key.

Example 
`HTTP.get("https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance")`

and this returns "HTTP.StatusError: received a '401 - Unauthorized' status in response"

The website has an API guide but the only help they give is an example using cURL `$ curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance`

I would appreciate any help

Links:
https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl

Comment: Using your example, might this work?
  `HTTP.get(https://keyid:keysecret@api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance`

Comment: trying to find the same answer.  Was this ever figured out?

Comment: Have you tried with: 

```julia
auth = base64encode(user * ":" * pass); HTTP.get(server, headers = ["Authorization" => "Basic $(auth)"])
``` ? It's working for me

Comment: Yes I was able to get it to work, sorry for not replying sooner. The code is below:

`temp = "Basic " * base64encode("your_api_key_here")
usr = Dict("Authorization" => temp)
balances = JSON.parse(String(HTTP.get("https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance"; headers = usr)))
`

Answer (score 0):

The API requires the key and secret code to be in the form:
`temp = Basic " + base64encode("your_api_key_here")`.

You then create a dictionary like so:
`usr = Dict("Authorization" => temp)`

and finally

`JSON.parse(String(HTTP.get("https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance"; headers = usr)))`

The `JSON.parse(String())` might need to change as I ran the code on quite an old Julia version last time this worked